# Flutter How to add specific text to each image on Home Page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-image, flutter-text

I tried to run the image by index from my image folder but I don't know how to implement specific to text to each image see here [image: my out put]

But I am unsure now how I can add specific text to each images by index

```
                        child: Container(
                          width: 160,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("img/city${index + 1}.jpg"),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              opacity: 0.7,
                            ),
                          ),
                        
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: \[
                            Text(
                              "City name",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                            ),
```

Comment: Can u be more specific about what you want ?

Comment: like i wanted to be able to see different text for each image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had already made demo for such view,

It might help u...

here is a code

```
List<Map<String,dynamic>> maplist=[
  {
    'country':'America',
    'imageurl':'lib/images/usa.jpg',
  },
  {
    'country':'India',
    'imageurl':'lib/images/india.jpg',
  },
  {
    'country':'China',
    'imageurl':'lib/images/china.jpg',
  },

];

class _Stack2State extends State<Stack2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 100,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount:maplist.length ,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return MyCard(map: maplist[index],
          );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

custom widget card

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> map;

  const MyCard({Key? key, required this.map}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: 160,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(map['imageurl']),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            opacity: 0.7,
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
              Text(
              map['country'],
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight
                      .
                  w600
              ),),],

            ),),);
  }
}
```

Comment: Upvote pls..so it can b useful to others

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create or import a list of strings with the elements that you want to display:

```
List<String> cities = [London, Paris, Madrid];
```

And then provide the list[index] to Text Widget:

```
           Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: \[
                        Text(
                          cities[index], //add this
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
```

Comment: thank you bro really you saved my life i was almost give up plus i am begginer, first time asking Question but it's legit wow

Comment: can i ask you one more question

Comment: sure you can and can you please mark my answer as correct as it helps me in giving more answers too